# Why does the replacement character keeps appearing when echoing variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm creating a test application and keeping the name of the person who is taking it on a table, along with the answers. The problem lies when I enter the following characters

> á é í ó ú ñ

I've tried some methods (like iconv function) but still not working.

```
//A sample of the code

require('../connect_db.php');
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$sql  =  "SELECT *
          FROM database.test";
$result     = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
$row        = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$name      = utf8decode($row[1]);

echo mb_detect_encoding($name); //Just to test
echo $name;
```

The result:

> UTF-8 G�mez

---

Edit: The problem is not on the database. I've manually entered names with these characters with no problem, so it must be the code.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated mysql_* API. Use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

There was no need to run the first `utf8decode()` when assigning values to `$name`

Instead I just called the function at the `echo`